# How to Order/Sort the structType based on the field names in Java Spark 2.1.1

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have a structType schema, i need to order / sort the schema based on the field name, below i am sharing the StructType.

```
StructType schema = StructType(StructField(zzz,StringType,true), 
                               StructField(kkk,StringType,true), 
                               StructField(aaa,StringType,true),
                               StructField(lll,StringType,true))
```

i would like to get the above structType, as below

```
StructType schema = StructType(StructField(aaa,StringType,true), 
                                   StructField(kkk,StringType,true), 
                                   StructField(lll,StringType,true),
                                   StructField(zzz,StringType,true))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java,

```
new StructType(Stream.of(schema.fields())
.sorted(Comparator.comparing(StructField::name))
.collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new StructField[schema.fields().length]))
```

In scala
You can do something like,

```
var schema = StructType(Seq(StructField("zzz",StringType,true), 
                            StructField("kkk",StringType,true), 
                            StructField("aaa",StringType,true),
                            StructField("lll",StringType,true)))
def reorderSchema: StructType => StructType = {schema => StructType(schema.sortBy(_.name))}
var newSchema = reorderSchema(schema)
```

Comment: As i am using java, the mentioned answer is  not working. we should pass the two parameters for sortBy(function f, order)